# how can i make layout it looks like instagram comment?

Tags: android

[image]

nickname is floating over comment body text.
It looks like css float effect.
I want to make layout this.

nickname has color, and clickable, and comment text are floating by nickname.

how can I do this for android?

Comment: I can think of a "hacky" way: Two overlapping TextViews. The first one contains the nickname and the comment. The second one only contains the nickname, with different style, `onClickListener`, etc.

Comment: try using `SpannableString` and `Html.FormHtml();`

Comment: if my answer helps to you than please accept so other can get help from your contribution :) thanks...

Answer (score 1):

hey i have implemented in my code using `SpannableString`

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("userName");

    final String tag = tagString.substring(start, i);
    spannableString.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            if (tag.equals("username")) {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {

        }
    }, 0, username.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```